# GeoPandas tranforming CRS: Cannot transform naive geometries. Please set a crs on the object first

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I create a `GeoDataFrame` like this

```
gdf = gp.GeoDataFrame([], columns=['foo', 'geometry'], crs = "epsg:4326")
```

Then I fill `gdf` with data. Then I want to transform the `CRS` of `gdf`

```
gdf.to_crs(epsg = "25833")
```

This gives me

> ValueError: Cannot transform naive geometries.  Please set a crs on the object first.

This confuses me. The output of `gdf.crs` is

```
<Geographic 2D CRS: EPSG:4326>
Name: WGS 84
Axis Info [ellipsoidal]:
- Lat[north]: Geodetic latitude (degree)
- Lon[east]: Geodetic longitude (degree)
Area of Use:
- name: World.
- bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

I tried

```
gdf.set_crs(epsg = "4326")
```

and then

```
gdf.to_crs(epsg = "25833")
```

and got the same result.

Why can't GeoPandas reproject the coordinates?

Comment: This actually should work and works fine for me on geopandas v0.9.0 and v0.10.0. What version are you using? Have you tried upgrading?

Comment: a **geopandas** constructor takes data and geometry in the constructor.  making a column called *geometry* does not mean it is geometry ....

Comment: @RobRaymond - if the geometry argument is not provided, geopandas looks for a "geometry" column in the data. The OP's question does provide a valid GeoDataFrame initialization as per the [GeoDataFrame docs](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html), which lists the `geometry` arg as optional. Using the OP's code, I get a gdf with a correctly initialized `EPSG:4326` length-0 geometry array.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Pandas 1.3.4, GeoPandas 0.10.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this `crs = "epsg:4326"` upon intialization of the `GeoDataFrame` (`gdf = gp.GeoDataFrame(...)`) does not seem like a good idea.

Besides that, setting the `CRS` must be done with an `inplace = True`.

```
gdf.set_crs(epsg = "4326", inplace = True)
```

Transforming too:

```
gdf.to_crs(epsg = "25833", inplace = True)
```

Comment: Why do you think initializing an empty GeoDataFrame with a CRS isn't a good idea? This seems like a reasonable thing to expect to work, and it works just fine for me with the latest versions of geopandas, including after assigning shapely geometries.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Because whenever I did it, it did not work.